# Active Time of Thread Java

Tags: java, multithreading

How Can I get active time of Thread for which it was actually in running state. Minus all the Waiting and Sleeping time.

I didn't seem to find anything in Thread API that gives me desired results.

If not exact code any ideas or Pseudo Codes would be great start.

Thanks

Comment: You can get the total CPU time with [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html#getCurrentThreadCpuTime--)

Comment: void run(){ long startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();//TODO:WORK  long endTime=System.currentTimeMillis(); System.out.println((endTime-startTime); }// this can be used just to calculate how long run function work

Answer (score 3):

Thanks assylias
The ThreadMXBean worked for me.. Here is sample code of what I did.

```
@Override
public void run() {
   System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
   try {
    for(int i = 999999999; i > 0; i--){}
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    ThreadMXBean threadBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
    long threadCpuTime = threadBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " :: " + threadCpuTime);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   return;
   }
}
```

I Put up a sleep of 5 seconds just to check if it was added to CPU time. It wasn't added. Also I put up empty for loop so that processing takes some time.

```
Here's Output
Thread-1 :: 15600200
Thread-4 :: 15700100
Thread-3 :: 15600100
Thread-0 :: 15500100
Thread-2 :: 0
```